# determining content of a cross vault on a ceiling-verfication

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, multiple-integral

I found this question as an old exam exercise, which I would like help for solving it properly...I've been starring at it for quiet a long time now.

As the title says, it is about determining the content of a cross vault on a ceiling.

I think it is defined by two half cylindric surfaces with radius 1 
on a square $ [-1,1] \times [-1,1] $ which are ''going through'' each other. I hope you understand what I mean ^^

The equations for the cylindric surfaces are given by

$ x_1^2 + x_3^2=1 , 0 \leq x_3 , |x_2| \leq 1 $

$x_2^2 + x_3 ^2 = 1 , 0\leq x_3, |x_1| \leq 1 $

Any help very appreciated

---

My progress on this task is following:

fix $x_3 $
therefore you get 
$x_1^2= 1-x_3^2 $ and $ x_2^2=1-x_3^2$

so $ - \sqrt{1-x_3^2} \leq x_1, x_2 \leq \sqrt{1-x_3^2}$

the surface on the square, will come to:

$ 4(1-x_3^2) $

And

$ \int_0^1 4(1-x_3^2) = 8/3 $

what do you think?